# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'user.CustomUser' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'user.CustomUser' that has not been installed

[image]

I am getting this error ..

My settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-+k2v!nn#f*qirqz1&4=de+eb&(f0hgvjd2)&^rg3i(w9z2=9dc'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'users/templates/dist',
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

pass


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'


def TemplateView(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/home.html')
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('age',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from users import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('', views.TemplateView, name='home'),

]
```

**admin.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'age', 'is_staff']


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**my file stestem**

[image: filesyestem]

How to solve this there is any idea .. I am stuck on it ..  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'user.CustomUser' that has not been installed . Though i have added AUTH_USER_MODEL in my **settings.py** . But it is not working

Comment: Your error says `user.CustomUser` not `users.CustomUser` (See the "s"). Either you have redeclared `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings or the settings file you show isn't your actual setting file.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
]
```

try to define your application at last index in Installapps

Comment: its not working ..